# setup apache as a service on linux

Tags: linux, apache, suse

I have installed apache and am currently using it in /app/apache2 path.  I want to have it run as a "service" on SUSE linux so that it starts up with the box.  What's the best way to do this, preferably without having to change my internal configurations or paths.

Answer (score 0):

start YaST and select System+System Services (Runlevel).

Search for apache2 and Enable the service.